# Can't download file using google cloud storage and Cloud Functions for Firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-functions

I am having the opposite as this issue:
[issues deleting an image using Cloud Functions for Firebase and @google-cloud/storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43178152/issues-deleting-an-image-using-cloud-functions-for-firebase-and-google-cloud-st)

(for the record, I have tried all things suggested there).

Basically I have a known file path, then a cloud function triggered by a database event.

I can initialise a bucket, get a file as well as its name, but then when I try and download it I get API Error: not found.

Here is my code:

```
module.exports = (orgID, reportID) => {
  const bucket = gcs.bucket("MY_PROJECT.appspot.com");

  const filePath = `/safety_hotline/${orgID}/${reportID}`;
  const file = bucket.file(filePath);

  // the name is shown correctly in the console
  console.log(file.name);

  const tempLocalFile = path.join(os.tmpdir(), filePath);
  const tempLocalDir = path.dirname(tempLocalFile);

  return mkdirp(tempLocalDir)
    .then(() => {
      // Download file from bucket.
      return file.download({ destination: tempLocalFile });
    })
    .then(() => {
      console.log("file downloaded succesfully");
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
}
```

[image]

You can see I get the console log of the file name, so I don't understand why I can't then download it?
Any advice would be amazing, thanks!

Edit: edited code a bit for clarity

Comment: Great Question!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see you have this line:

```
  const filePath = `/safety_hotline/${orgID}/${reportID}`;
```

I am guessing that you may have named your objects with the pattern `safety_hotline/org/report`, but as written above the first character of the object name would be a slash. That's also a legal object name but it's usually unintentional. Try removing the slash?

Comment: Oh my god that was it... I feel stupid now! Thanks so much, now can actually get back to work!

Comment: It will only let me award the bounty in one day so I will then, thanks so much though

Comment: Glad that was it! I only knew what to look for because I've done exactly that several times now.

Comment: Haha well, hard won knowledge right there. Given the potential for this mistake to be made, do you think I should change the title or something so it's more search oriented to that particular problem?

Answer (score 0):

> **You Try This Follow** [**functions-samples**](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/quickstarts/thumbnails/functions/index.js)  **?**

i'am try this follow done Download file successful

Comment: Thanks for the response but this is example uses a storage trigger rather than a database trigger. For a storage trigger I can download etc, because I'm using object.bucket (based off of the event object), but I need to be able to run this from a database event as I need more control.