# Can't Download File From Cloud Storage to Cloud Function Temporary Storage to Read and Process CSV Import

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to use a firebase onCall funtion to download a CSV file from Cloud Storage, place it in cloud function temporary storage, then read it and upload it into a firestore collection called test. Unfortunately, I can't get the download to cloud function temporary storage to work.

I have tried to follow the google documentation at https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/extend-with-functions and other examples with the "return bucket.file(filePath).download({destination: tempFilePath}), but without luck.

Here is my code

```
//THIS IS THE FUNCTION FOR LOADING AN PROCESSING A INCOMING CSV FILE
exports.uploadCSV = functions.https.onCall((data,context)=> {

    //get the file name from the boday
    const fileOne = data.id + '.csv';
        console.log('fileOne', fileOne);

    //bring together the director and file name
    const fileName = 'uploads/' + fileOne;
        console.log('fileName', fileName);

    //setup the temporary path
    const tmpFilePath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), fileName);
        console.log('tmpFilePath', tmpFilePath);

    //assign the Firbase project id
    const projectId = 'xxxxxxxxx';
        console.log('projectId')

    //assign storage to the project
    const storage = new Storage({ projectId: projectId });
        console.log('new Storage')

    //setup the bucket configuration
    const bucket = admin.storage().bucket();
        console.log('bucket', bucket)

    //Reference Storage Bucket in firestore
    const bucketName = 'xxxxxxxxx.appspot.com';
        console.log('bucketName');

    //sets myFile to value of file downloaded into cloud function temporary storage.
    return storage.bucket(bucketName).file(fileName).download({destination: tmpFilePath})
        .then(() => {
            console.log('image downloaded to:', tmpFilePath)
                    //read stream and process
            fs.createReadStream('tmpFilePath')
                .pipe(csv())
                .on('data', (row) => {
                    console.log(row);
                    if(row) {
                        firestore.collection('test').add({
                            name: row.Name
                        });
                    } else {console.log('no data')
                    }
                })
                .on('end', () => {
                    console.log('CSV file successfully processed.');
                });

        })
        .then(() => {
                //removes temporary directory
                return fs.unlink(tmpFilePath);
        })
        .catch((err)=>{ console.log(err); });

});
```

While the Network console returns a 200, this is the error I receive in my firebase-functions logs.

{ Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/tmp/uploads/somedata.csv'
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: '/tmp/uploads/somedata.csv' }

Answer (score 2):

Your download path includes a folder called "uploads", but you never create that directory explicitly.  Instead, try just downloading to os.tmpdir() without any intermediate directories to create:

```
// no "uploads" here
const fileName = fileOne;
    console.log('fileName', fileName);

const tmpFilePath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), fileName);
    console.log('tmpFilePath', tmpFilePath);
```

Comment: Doug, thank you for taking the time to answer my question, love your firecasts videos. I tried doing what you suggested, but received a no such object log, because the file is sitting in the directory uploads/. I tried explicitly setting the directory like in the example below, but get a cannot read property 'then' of after setting the directory, which seems to be a promise issue. I would love any other suggestions you might have. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45759822/cant-download-file-using-google-cloud-storage-and-cloud-functions-for-firebase

Comment: I was able to get the file downloaded successfully by adding const tmpDirPath = path.dirname(tmpFilePath); and then using mkdirp(tmpDirPath using the npm dependency mkdirp. The createReadStream has a few issues for anyone that is trying to copy the work, like you need to use .setEncoding('utf8') to get the data. Thank again Doug for getting me another step down the road.